# Cannot extend Windows non-system partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

Below is a screenshot of the Disk Management tool:

[image]

I'm trying to expand my Data (D:) partition, but the 'Extend Volume' option is greyed out. I have tried to extend the volume in command prompt using `diskpart` but the following error code was thrown: `There is not enough usable free space on specified disk(s) to extend the volume.`

Is there any way to extend that partition?

Comment: Only third-party software can help in your case. And I strongly recommend to backup your data before. But when you make backup you can simply remove D: and re-create it with the size you need. **PS.** You have 2 problems: a) unallocated space is behind the volume you want to extend; b) you have 4 basic volumes (primary partitions), so you cannot create any additional partition (primary or extended) for to use it as a temporary one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `D:` partition is at the end of the disk, so cannot be extended beyond the end.

You need to move the partition so that the Unallocated space
*follows the partition*,
and then the extend option will become available.

Just to warn that an error in partition move can destroy the data on the disk,
if partitions are over-written,
so best to ensure that you have excellent backups for the whole disk
before starting.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for hours checking google to find a right solution. After searching I found the best solution is installing mini tool partition. It's the champion do everything with few clicks without any issue.
Trying install mini tool partition and then open it. Click the drive that you want to extend and then pop opens and shows the option to select which drive to take space from and click ok. It easy and works perfectly.

Comment: Now it is sounding like spam.  Are you associated with it ?

Comment: @RohitGupta its not a spam. I have tried it and i succeed so i added the answer. please try and check so you can understand it is working. version i used is mini tool partition version 12. its very simple to use, partitioning by using mini tool partition is excellent.