# Extend C Drive next to system reserved partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to extend my C drive. but the system reserved partition is right next to it. What should I do? I don't really want to delete the recovery in fear of it not booting if windows gets messed up.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot extend Windows non-system partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1380400/cannot-extend-windows-non-system-partition)

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend creating a full system backup using the "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" in Control Panel and choosing "Create a system image" in the left column.  This says "Windows 7" but it works on Windows 10.  Also create a system repair disk when it asks you.  This will make it more likely you're able to restore if something gets broken.  To be extra safe you might want to make an additional backup with another program.

Then you can use a third party partition editor that offers more functionality.  I can't vouch for either, but I believe EaseUS Partition Master or GParted may be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i did. I used easeus partition master, as normal disk manager does not allow you to modify the recovery partitions, its restricted.

I then extended the recoverypartition to 120gb from the unallocated space.
Then i shrunk the recover partition back to 1gb and made sure to shrink it to the LEFT, so the unallocated space would slide to the left, and be adjacent to the C drive. This is done by sliding the bar in the ease UI to the left instead of to the right to shrink...

Then i extended the C drive with the unallocated space as it became adjacent in disk manager. I noticed that EASEUS actually renamed it and it shows up as WinRE. It also shows up as a healthy partiton and not recovery in disk manager. I was worried that it might have gotten messed up and no longer recognized by the system. I then ran this command in elevated powershell reagentc /info to make sure that i didnt mess up the recovery partition, and it confirmed that it still existed and was recognized by powershell as occupying partition 4, which it did. So dont worry disk manager was just kinda dumb and was a false alarm!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I installed mini tool partition and then open it. Click the drive that you want to extend and then pop opens and shows the option to select which drive to take space from and click ok. It easy and works perfectly.

Comment: There is the same answer on another [question](https://superuser.com/a/1828510/466828)

Comment: @RohitGupta no i saw both questions are asked by different members and if it becomes useful for them and that's why I put the answer in both posts. i am sorry. understand me.